# Hi, I have a problem in the data list. After displaying the information, I want to get the product code by clicking on a in the data list

Tags: asp.net, webforms, datalist

I still couldn't get the output from the program. I put a text in the data list to display the product ID by clicking on it, but it didn't work and only the ID of the first product is displayed.

```xml
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4" style="width:auto">
  <div class="card border-left-info shadow h-100 py-2">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
        <div class="col mr-2">
          <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-info text-uppercase mb-1">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NameKala") %>' />
          </div>
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdKala") %>' /> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="progress progress-sm mr-2">
                <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="50" class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <h4 onclick="myFunctio3()">
            <i id="I3" class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true">
            </i> &nbsp; open
          </h4>
          <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="heden4" style="display:none"> 
        <p> test
          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdKala") %>' /> 
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My output should be in such a way that in each line of the data list that is clicked, display the product ID of that line or section.

Comment: There is no list or collection of any kind anywhere in this code sample. You need to provide code that matches with your problem description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.